# How to improve performance of upload file by websocket

Tags: javascript, python, performance, file-upload, websocket

I have implemented an app about upload big file(Most scenes more than 1 GB) from client to server.

1. In the client I used the HTML5 File API, sliced file into pieces(I have tested 1MB/5MB/10MB) and uploaded by WebSocket.
2. In the server used tornado as the websocket server. Our customer didn't allow to use plugin such as applet, also http-upload was not appropriate in our scene, so i have to choose HTML5 and websocket.

My problem was that the process was too slow. For transferring a 40 MB file as example, it took about 40s.

- Process dataing (encoding, decoding and so on) in both client and server took about 5s.
- Transfer data from websocket client to websocet server took about 35s.

Could anyone tell me what's the problem?

My server side code used python-tornado and is very simple:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([(r'/litevirt-websocket/realtime/',RealtimeHandler),],**settings)
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

My client side code just uses the standard HTML5 File API which is unnecessary to attach here.

Comment: An upload speed of 1Mbyte/s seems pretty good for most Internet connections. If you want something faster pay for an expensive Symmetric link.

Comment: You don't need applets or plugins to do an HTTP upload; a simple form can do it, without even any JS code…

Comment: My software are planned to used in LAN with 100MB network card. I have tested form post which can reach speed of 10MB/s(FTP is more faster). But because some season form post is not appropriate in our scene. Can everybody give me some help about why websocket is so slow than form post and how to advance the transfer speed of websocket. Thank you very much!

Comment: I added log in tornado code, and found that the fllowing codes spent too long time on websocket.py-->WebSocketProtocol13-->_apply_mask function. which's core code are:for i in xrange(len(data)):
            unmasked[i] = unmasked[i] ^ mask[i % 4]